# How to specify thrift include folder in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, scrooge

I have a hard time setting the scroogeThriftIncludeFolders for Scrooge (https://github.com/twitter/scrooge).

In my build.sbt I already use the default settings via

```
com.twitter.scrooge.ScroogeSBT.newSettings
```

How do I configure the scroogeThriftIncludeFolders?

Comment: What directories do you want included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we now include thrift files from other modules/projects we use the Scrooge possibility to include thrift files coming from jar (classpath) dependencies like this in our build.sbt:

```
scroogeThriftDependencies in Compile := Seq("service-xxx-api_2.10", "service-yyy-api_2.10")
```